# Do linear continua contain $\mathbb{R}$? Can a nontrivial connected space have only trivial path components?

Tags: general-topology, order-theory, connectedness, path-connected

Consider a connected space $X$ under the order topology, such that $X$ contains at least two elements. Does there exist a subspace of $X$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$? If there isn't, then $X$ has only trivial path components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another way to get a counterexample.  Let $L$ be any totally ordered set that does not embed in $\mathbb{R}$ (e.g. $L=\omega_1$, or any totally ordered set of cardinality greater than $\mathfrak{c}$).  Define a sequence of totally ordered sets $Y_0\subset Y_1\subset Y_2\subset\dots$ as follows.  Let $Y_0=\mathbb{Q}$ (or really any totally ordered set with more than one point).  Given $Y_n$, define $Y_{n+1}$ to be $Y_n$ with a copy of $L$ inserted right after each element of $Y_n$.  (If you like, $Y_{n+1}=Y_n\times (1+L)$ with the lexicographic order.)

Now let $Y=\bigcup_n Y_n$, and let $X$ be the Dedekind completion of $Y$.  Note that $Y$ is a dense linear order, since if $x,y\in Y_n$ with $x<y$ then in $Y_{n+1}$ there is a whole copy of $L$ between $x$ and $y$.  Thus $X$ is a complete dense linear order, and thus is connected in the order topology.  But between any two points of $X$ there is a copy of $L$, and so no interval in $X$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.  It follows easily that no subspace of $X$ in the order topology is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 3):

Consider $X = [0,1]^{\omega_1}$ with the dictionary order. The property that $f, h \in X \Rightarrow \exists g : f < g < h$ follows readily so I'll skip that. The least upper bound property holds as well ([Does $[0,1]^{\mathbb{\lambda}}$ have the least upper bound property under the dictionary order?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2317588/444923)) so we conclude $X$ is a linear continuum.

We prove for $f < g$ such that $f$ and $g$ are eventually $0$ that there is no path $\phi : [0,1] \to X$ such that $\phi(0) = f$ and $\phi(1) = g$.

Let $\alpha$ be an element of $\omega_1$ such that $f$ and $g$ are $0$ for all elements greater than $\alpha$. Consider $\beta \in \omega_1$ with $\beta > \alpha$ and $f_{\beta} \in X$ which agrees with $f$ everywhere except at $\beta$ and has $f_{\beta}(\beta) := f(\beta) + 1$.

Define $I_{\beta} := (f_{\beta+1}, f_\beta)$. Each $I_\beta$ is a disjoint open subset of $[f,g]$ which is nonempty by the linear continuum property. There are uncountably many such $\beta$ so $[f,g]$ cannot be homeomorphic to $[0,1]$ and we conclude there is no path connecting $f$ and $g$.

Now let $f$ and $g$ be arbitrary elements of $X$. We prove there exists $f_0, g_0$ which are eventually zero such that $f < f_0 < g_0 < g$. Let $\alpha$ be the first element such that $f(\alpha) \neq g(\alpha)$, so $f(\alpha) < g(\alpha)$. Pick $f_0$ and $g_0$ such that they agree with $f$ and $g$ before $\alpha$, such that $f(\alpha) < f_0(\alpha) < g_0(\alpha) < g(\alpha)$ - which is possible since $[0,1]$ is a linear continuum, and such that $f_0$ and $g_0$ are zero after $\alpha$. Then the relation holds by definition of the dictionary order.

Therefore the closed interval between any two points contains a closed interval which is not path connected and so cannot be path connected.

---

I asked if $[0,1]^{\omega}$ under the dictionary order topology has only trivial path components and Niels Diepeveen answered this affirmatively (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2318699/444923).

The nice thing about this linear continuum is that it has the same cardinality as the reals whereas $[0,1]^{\omega_1}$ has the cardinality of the power set of the reals. Therefore there's the uninsightful reason that $[0,1]^{\omega_1}$ has only trivial path components that its closed intervals have a different cardinality than that of a real interval.

Comment: did you simultaneously post a question and its answer? Both were posted exactly 12 min ago. Did you have your answer ready and typed when you posted your question?

Comment: well I guess this is what you did, and it seems to be acceptable ... well, the answer is nice, and here is who says it is ok to do this (subject to certain mild assumptions): https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20447/is-it-ok-to-post-a-question-you-already-know-the-answer-with-the-only-purpose-to and https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15017/can-i-post-a-question-and-an-answer-just-because-i-think-it-helps-others

Comment: @Mirko Yes. I've been typing my questions and then trying to answer them to the best of my ability. If I think I answered my question I'll include it with the "answer your own question feature".

Comment: if you like general topology you should show up at the coming Summer topology conference :) https://www.udayton.edu/artssciences/academics/mathematics/events/topology-conference-2017/welcome/index.php and if you like lex order in product spaces, you may find interesting the open question whether the countable power of the Sorgenfrey line is a D-space https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102785280

Comment: I might just come :)

Comment: you missed the early registration deadline ... but you might try the "Funding" link at the conference web site, in case they have some money left

Comment: I believe my construction actually gives a space with the cardinality of the reals (at least if you take $L$ to be complete and have cardinality at most that of the reals).  Since $L$ is complete and the construction of $Y$ is by an induction of length $\omega$, you will only need to fill gaps of cofinality $\omega$ in $Y$ in order to complete it.